# the pointer to a object in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question about pointer to a object in C++.
For example, if we have a CRectangle class and there is a y variable in it.

```
CRectangle *x = new CRectangle;
```

`x->y` means member y of object pointed by x, what about `(*x).y`? are they the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `x->y` and `(*x).y` are exactly the same in your example.  The `->` means dereference X, and `*x` means exactly the same.

Comment: Alexander Gessier's answer contains a valid point:  as long as your CRectangle class didn't overload operator-> and operator* to do something unexpected.

Comment: No, you can't overload `operator*` to behave differently for `CRectangle *`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `(*x).y` is equivalent to `x->y` if `x` is of a pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can see it by yourself with this sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
    int width, height;
    public:
    void set_values (int, int);
    int area (void) {return (width * height);}
};

void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b) {
    width = a;
    height = b;
}

int main () {
    CRectangle r1, *r2;
    r2= new CRectangle;
    r1.set_values (1,2);
    r2->set_values (3,4);
    cout << "r1.area(): " << r1.area() << endl;
    cout << "r2->area(): " << r2->area() << endl;
    cout << "(*r2).area(): " << (*r2).area() << endl;

    delete r2;
    return 0;
}
```